# How do I process different delimiters in a RegEx expression with Java?

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I am working on creating a program for my course, in which I am required to divide the string: `This;is;the;first;line;;This;is;the;second;line!;;;;Done!;;`.

In the requirements, I need to read a `single semicolon` as a `space`, and a `double semicolon` as a `new line`. How do I create a regular expression in the useDelimiter() method that allows me to parse through and differentiate between both `;` and `;;`? Thank you!

Assignment Excerpt:
*Instead of hard-coding the string, this time you will read it from the console.  Study the useDelimiter() method and use it to set the delimiter for the scanner input. This time allow either colons or semicolons as the delimiters.  One might prefer to use the String Tokenizer here, but don’t -- use the Scanner’s useDelimiter() method to set the delimiter in the Scanner and process each token as it comes.*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hw3p2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initializes scanner class.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompts user for input.
        System.out.println("Enter the string you wish to filter & parse: ");

        // Reads user input.
        String filterString = input.nextLine();

        // Initiates new scanner reading the user inputted string.
        Scanner a = new Scanner(filterString);

        a.useDelimiter(";|;;");

        System.out.printf("\n");

        // Loop that parses through string while there are more tokens.
        while(a.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(a.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The Expected output is to be:

[image: Code output]

Comment: Does it have to be done using `Scanner` only?

Comment: Scanner is not capable of doing this job properly. The solution is trivial: Don't use scanner. Presumably this is as simple as splitting on double colon first, then splitting each result you get from that on single colons, or even just a simple `.replace(";", " ")` call.

Comment: @rzwitserloot That is a correct way to do it, and is how we made a program previous to this. Our professor wants us to expand upon using the useDelimiter() method with scanner input rather than hardcoding the string.

Comment: @Anubhava While it doesn't necessarily have to be solely the Scanner, that is the direction in which our professor is pushing us. He wants us to take input from the console, and use the useDelimiter() method to parse through and add the spaces / new lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```
public class Hw3p2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initializes scanner class.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(";;");

        // Prompts user for input.
        System.out.print("Enter the string you wish to filter & parse: ");

        // Reads user input.
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            String filterString = input.next();
            //System.err.println("filterString: " + filterString);

            // Initiates new scanner reading the user inputted string.
            Scanner a = new Scanner(filterString).useDelimiter(";");

            // Loop that parses through string while there are more tokens.
            while(a.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(a.next() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            a.close();
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```bash
Enter the string you wish to filter & parse: This;is;the;first;line;;This;is;the;second;line!;;;;Done!;;
This is the first line 
This is the second line! 

Done!
```

Note use of outer scanner with delimiter `;;` and an inner one with `;`.